# Tank Track Animation

Tags: animation

recently I wanted to get into animation, and I was wondering how I'd go about animating tank tracks, most of the tutorials I've seen involve having tracks made from scratch and I'm trying to animate a tank I built myself from a game, I was wondering if anyone had any advice on what I should do.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Blender will animate it for you :).

1. Create the track using an Array modifier
2. Add a Bezier circle and Curve modifier to create the shape
3. Move the Bezier circle - the track will automatically rotate

<sup>Note:
The track and Bezier curve position needs to be exactly like in this gif. Both from profile. Otherwise it won't work.</sup>

[image]