# How to rotate tank treads animation using Bezier circle

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I have made an animation of tank treads animating along the x axis. Once I try to animate from the 51st frame to rotate into the Y axis, the whole mesh turns into chaos. What am I doing incorrect? I have tried merging the modifiers, but the animation of the treads then all become one mesh. I also saw this post but it doesn't show how to rotate the treads along rotating axis.

[Tank Track Animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209127/tank-track-animation)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you parent the object to the curve, or if you parent both the object and the curve to an empty, it will work fine, as the axis will remain relative to the parent. If you don't, the object will go wild as you'll change the deform axis. Note that I also had to animate the tank treads on the right axis so that it moves along the curve, but it is the empty that makes it rotate.

[image]

Comment: I'm obviously doing something incorrect, I did try both ways, but the tank treads instead of  circulating motion, they just slide as one object when I parent them, so I have included the file if someone can had a look what I have set up incorrect.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=8kDkdAJ4" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/8kDkdAJ4/)

Comment: I don't see any problem in your file, move the object to the curve, keyframe the object so that it is animated, move the empty to move both object and curve

Comment: Ok I understand how it kinda works, but it looks odd when I rotate the tank treads because they dont animate while they turn. Please take a look at my animation.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=PZMJSsSa" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/PZMJSsSa/)

Comment: it's the empty that you need to move and rotate, and parent both object and curve to empty

Comment: Ok, so in this file, you'll be able to spot the problem, I have set the keyframes for the empty as the curve and object are parented to the empty, and when it animates, the tank treads don't do nothing but glide across the scene.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=x8NryKXg" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/x8NryKXg/)

Comment: you also need to animate the object, in your case on the Y axis, so create one location keyframe at frame 0 and at frame 100 move it on the Y axis and keyframe again, also in the Dope Sheet (or Timeline) press T to choose Linear

Comment: because as the object is now parented to the empty it is as if it was not moving along the curve when it is moved by the empty  ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help and info!